# Wiggle Value in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there an equivalent in geometry nodes to the Wiggle Vector/Wiggle Number/etc. in Animation Nodes? I don't see any "wiggle" values in geometry nodes.

[image]

I know one workaround would be using animation modifiers to create some noise and then drive values in geometry nodes with that noise, but I'd prefer something less complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a texture, such as the Noise texture. The `Fac` value varies for different input vectors, so feeding in the Scene Time in Seconds will result in a wiggle-like animation.

[image]

You can adjust the speed and qualities of the wiggle by changing the Noise parameters.